# IMG_Load doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, sdl-2

I was watching this series = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NVgHrOFneg
and for some reason for the guy in the video the code works but for me it compiles fine but doesn't load an image. I really don't know what to do.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL_image.h"

SDL_Texture *LoadTexture(std::string filePath, SDL_Renderer *renderTarget) //texture optimization function
{


    SDL_Texture *texture = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load(filePath.c_str());


    if (surface == NULL)
        std::cout << "Error 1" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderTarget, surface);

        if (texture == NULL)
            std::cout << "Error 2" << std::endl;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return texture;
}



int main(int, char *argv[])
{
    const int FPS = 144;
    int frameTime = 0;

    SDL_Window *window = nullptr;

    SDL_Texture *currentImage= nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer *renderTarget = nullptr;
    SDL_Rect playerRect;
    int frameWidth, frameHeight;
    int textureWidth, textureHeight;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG;

    if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) != imgFlags))

    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << IMG_GetError()    << std::endl;



    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Pong", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1024, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderTarget = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    currentImage = LoadTexture("Untitled.jpg", renderTarget);
    SDL_QueryTexture(currentImage, NULL, NULL, &textureWidth, &textureHeight);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderTarget, 0xFF, 0, 0, 0xFF);
    frameWidth = textureWidth / 3;
    frameHeight = textureHeight / 4;
    playerRect.x = playerRect.y = 0;
    playerRect.y = frameWidth;
    playerRect.h = frameHeight;

    bool isRunning = true; //game loop
    SDL_Event ev;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)
        {

            if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                isRunning = false;
        }


    frameTime++;

    if (FPS / frameTime == 4)
    {

        frameTime = 0;
        playerRect.x += frameWidth;
        if (playerRect.x >= textureWidth)
            playerRect.x =0;

        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderTarget);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderTarget, currentImage, &playerRect, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);

    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(currentImage);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderTarget);
    window = nullptr;

    renderTarget = nullptr;
    currentImage  = nullptr;

    SDL_Quit();


    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNvYo.jpg

Comment: It _does_ work, so you need to perform some debugging because you made a mistake. Also not sure why you posted this as an inline-runnable HTML snippet.

Comment: oh I didnt know how to post normal code , sorry. I should probably give more detail, the error message is in the main function
 printf("IMG_Init: Failed to init required jpg and png support!\n");
 printf("IMG_Init: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
part , its REALLY frustrating

Comment: So which error is displayed.....? There's not much point having `printf` output if you're not going to read it!!!

Comment: This is the error message: http://imgur.com/LHMdt5F , what does that mean ?

Comment: Please please please.... http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Make it neat and tidy and compact and _in the question_. That output's weird, though. Did you install your libraries properly?

Comment: if I do "std::cout << "Error: " << IMG_GetError << std::endl;" indstead i get this error : http://imgur.com/ATXcr9y

Comment: That's because you're printing a decimal representation of the location in memory of the function `IMG_GetError`. The expression is `IMG_GetError()`.

Comment: i know , but if I do it properly this comes up: http://imgur.com/TUI7il6

Comment: I don't see how that's a reason to do it _even more wrong_!

Comment: well I guess so , but I thought that it was some error code but I thought it was an error message code I could google ? I guess not.

Comment: No, it's just wrong: it's the address of the `IMG_GetError` function, not the result of _calling_ that function. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tidied it up a little bit , is that better? I would really like to get that working soon.

Answer (score 0):

`IMG_Init` returns bitfield of formats that was initialised. If resulting bitfield doesn't contain every format that was requested in `flags`, something gone wrong.

`if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) != imgFlags))` checks if there is **no** error. Then you're trying to get error message, but there were no errors. Remove negation operator.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the .exe and run it from an IDE it often stores the executable in a ../bin/.. directory. If Untitled.jpg is in the same directory as your source files, it will not find it.

SDL_GetBasePath(); will return the base path to your files. Check it out docs for it.

The string from SDL_GetBasePath() + "Untitled.jpg" will find and open the file.